# Java search at text a list of variables

Tags: java

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I googled for this question, but had no good info about it.

I own a text with about 3 million words. My need is to do a search for words in this text, I have a list of all those words and I need to find the same in this text, I would like the help of companions for a good idea how to do this with a result of meaningful time.

Thanks for the help.

Best regard´s.

Comment: Will you need to search for words several times or just once?

Comment: Do you need to find all the instances of a specific word, or just decide if the word is in the text?

Comment: Sorry for the less of data in the post, I need to search each word all the time in the input text. I´m reading this input text via .txt loaded with BufferedReader. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Comment: I already used Lucene with Zend Framework at php, but for one search at one text, could I be used to several searchs inside a text loaded with BufferedReader? Thanks.

Comment: Sure its possible: to gain an idea have a look at this example http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/

Comment: Thanks again, I will test this example with a .txt file as entrance and an ArrayList with the words to match.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very inneficient to search the text each time from the text file.

If memory is not a constrain you can add each word in Arraylist and do binary search by

```
Collections.binarySearch() API
```

Comment: That´s a great idea too, load each word to the coolection and search by binary, but I need to convert the words to binary to match the words in the list, don´t? Thanks.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ferrari: binary search has nothing to do with binary format. It is an efficient recursive algorithm that partitions the collection and searches on increasingly smaller sub-collections. It finds an element in O(log(N)) instead of O(N), but requires the collection to be sorted.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ferrari. Not needed. U can use the normal string comparisons. As Tudor said its the most efficient way to search sorted item.

Comment: Thanks, will try these usage and the Lucene idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check these libraries, http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/

Comment: Great one, it will be studed during the software development. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search for the words only once, then I don't think you can do better than just a linear search over the text.

If you need to do several searches, then you will need to index your text and maybe use something like Lucene.

Comment: Yeah, I need to search over the text several times, 50.000 times is the small search at a text with 3 million words. Thanks.